# HOW TO ADD FACEBOOK ICON IN THE FOOTER USING ASP.NET MVC 4 or later

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

when you look at the code below:

```
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <p><strong>FOLLOW US</strong></p>
                <p>@Html.ActionLink("Twitter", "#", "#")</p>
                <p>@Html.ActionLink("Facebook", "#", "#")</p>
                <p>@Html.ActionLink("Google+", "#", "#")</p>
            </div>
```

I want to replace `@Html.ActionLink("Google+", "#", "#")` with a Google plus Icon.

Comment: Then replace the link with an image?  What exactly is the issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the link to be an image, make it an image.  I don't think there's an HTML helper for it, but you can always use `Url.ActionLink` to get the part you need:

```
<a href="@Url.ActionLink("#", "#")"><img src="yourimage.png" alt="Google+" /></a>
```